Github Codespaces Inertia.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
In GitHub Codespaces, I'm experiencing issues with loading resources like client.js, app.js, and Home.vue through port 5173, leading to "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" errors. I'm looking for a way to properly configure this port or an alternative solution to this problem.
